# How to use HTMLHelper for other file types?

Tags: header, htmlhelper, web-app-manifest

I found samples where HTMLHelper was used to load some types of files like stylesheets, scripts and images:

```
$this->addHeadLink(HTMLHelper::_('image', 'joomla-favicon.svg', '', [], true, 1), 'icon', 'rel', ['type' => 'image/svg+xml']);
```

The subject code will search for `joomla-favicon.svg` in the sub-folder `images` for the current template. For Joomla 4.2 the long answer is `/media/templates/site/my_template/images/joomla-favicon.svg`.
In the same manner:

```
HTMLHelper::_('script', 'my.js', ['version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true]);
```

can be used my.js to be loaded from `js` folder.

What about using HTMLHelper::_ for other file types? Can I have a subfolder named 'files' and force HTMLHelper to use it for a function like `addHeadLink`?
My particular task is to add a head link for Web app manifest, which I can do simply by `addHeadLink`, but I'm curious if I could use `HTMLHelper::_` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not out of the box. The method handling this, `Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper::includeRelativeFiles()`, and related methods are protected. You'd have to extend the `HTMLHelper` class to gain access to the method. It's also worth mentioning that currently this method always looks up files with `.min` suffix first, even when looking for images (which do not use it at all). This adds additional I/O load, making the method unnecessarily slow. It's actually a bug, it has been reported exactly 2 years ago but hasn't been fixed yet. Anyways, you're better off writing your own method.